# Disambiguate between blobs from notes and other blobs from files?

Tags: git

How can I know that the following blobs, e.g. an extract as this:

```
["text", "143e875f50d1f6b645750cfc3d146842a3644eaa",30,40,"89/accfaa73947d063acb5e4dccf6a4816226e1ec"]
```

extracted with

```cpp
echo "Get all blobs > ${fileSizeThreshold} bytes."
git rev-list --objects "${what}" \
| git cat-file --batch-check='"%(objecttype)","%(objectname)",%(objectsize),%(objectsize:disk),"%(rest)"' \
| sed -n 's/^"blob",//p' \
| awk -F',' '$2'">= ${fileSizeThreshold}" \
| sort -t "," --numeric-sort --key=2 > ${outDir}/largeBlobs
```

are not blobs from the **note** section in commits: I converted with `svn2git`.
I see that this sha1 hash is contained in `git notes` which outputs all note blobs...

Comment: did you try to filter out blobs given from: `git rev-list --objects $(cat .git/refs/notes/commits)` ?

Comment: no not really, seems to work: what is inside `.git/refs/notes/commit`

Comment: the head of a "branch" of "commits" of notes. Notes are actually stored as commits pointing to the anoted commits, and thus the files points to the HEAD commit of notes (just like refs/heads/mybranch holds the commit to the HEAD of 'mybranch'.

Comment: I think then my `${what}` argument can be `--all --not $(cat refs/notes/commits)` on a server repo ? Correct?

Answer (score 0):

A blob is simply Git's way of storing file data.

Suppose you make a note whose contents require a blob containing `89/accfaa73947d063acb5e4dccf6a4816226e1ec`, *and* for some reason *I* store an actual *file* whose contents are `89/accfaa73947d063acb5e4dccf6a4816226e1ec`.  One single blob object will be used to hold both items.

Hence, the key is not to try to disambiguate after the fact, but rather to enumerate whatever is of interest.  In particular:

> ```
> git rev-list --objects "${what}"
> ```

should send you straight to [the `git rev-list` documentation section on `--objects`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---objects), where it says:

> **--objects**
>   Print the object IDs of any object referenced by the listed commits. `--objects foo ^bar` thus means “send me all object IDs which I need to download if I have the commit object *bar* but not *foo*”.

The list of commit-trees that `git rev-list` will walk is thus determined by your `${what}` argument, which you have not shown.

Comment: my ${what} argument is `--all`

Comment: `--all` means "all references"; adding `--not refs/notes/commits` (no `cat` needed) should indeed help. You might want to start with a less-inclusive option than `--all` instead, though, since `--all` includes (e.g.) the stash `refs/stash`, replacements (`refs/replace/*`), and so on. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, `git rev-list --objects` is not alone: you also have `git rev-list --object-names`.

Git 2.41 (Q2 2023) documents what the pathname-looking strings in "`rev-list --object`" output are for and what they mean.

See [commit 15364d2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15364d2a3cef397442033a3fec27d57007ca1c51) (28 Mar 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit abb3b69](https://github.com/git/git/commit/abb3b692a4aaa2b9a34e32f171aa7d829d3d26b9), 04 Apr 2023)</sup>

> ### [`docs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15364d2a3cef397442033a3fec27d57007ca1c51): document caveats of `rev-list`'s `object-name` output
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> At first glance, the names given by "`rev-list --objects`" seem like a good way to see which paths are present in a set of commits.
> But there are some subtle gotchas there.
> We do not document the format of the names at all, so let's do so, along with warning of these problems.
>
> I intentionally did not document the exact format of the names here, as I don't think it's something we want people to rely on (though I doubt in practice that we'd change it at this point).
>
> Though all of this is historically tied to "--objects", these days we have a separate "`--object-names`" flag which can turn the names off or on.
> So I put the detailed documentation there, but added a note from `--objects` (which did not otherwise mention the names at all, even though they are on by default).

`rev-list-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/15364d2a3cef397442033a3fec27d57007ca1c51/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L885):

> `object _bar_` but not `_foo_''`. See also `--object-names` below.

`rev-list-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/15364d2a3cef397442033a3fec27d57007ca1c51/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L915-L920):

> Note that the
> "name" of each object is ambiguous, and mostly intended as a
> hint for packing objects.
>
> In particular: no distinction is made between
> the names of tags, trees, and blobs; path names may be modified
> to remove newlines; and if an object would appear multiple times
> with different names, only one name is shown.